# Python - BeautifulSoup: Pull stock data from Morningstar

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract the two data points from Morning Star website for a list of companies and save it to a text file, but I am not sure how to approach this task. Below is my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

thislist = ["AAPL","FB","TSLA","DIS"] 
for symbol in thislist:
    print ('Getting data for ' + symbol + '...\n')

# extract from this website
url="https://www.morningstar.com/stocks/xnas/" + symbol + "/quote"
        
soup = BS(url)
        
# Find the Value of Last Close Price
for text in soup.find_all('div class', name_='Last Close'):
    Last_Close = text.find_all('dp-value price-down')
    print(Last_Close)     
        
# Find the Value of its Market Cap
for text in soup.find_all('div class', name_='Market Cap'):
    Market_Cap = text.find_all('dp-value')
    print(Market_Cap)      
        
# Print the table
print(symbol, Last_Close, Market_Cap)
            
# Save the data in a .txt file
df.to_csv(r'c:\data\testing.txt', header=None, index=None, sep=' ', mode='a')
```

Comment: Ok, but what's the issue? You have to clearly state why this is not doing what you want [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please show us the existing output or error message.

Comment: Also, make sure to tag Python questions [tag:python], so they get seen by people faster. And this one is also about [tag:web-scraping]. (You could browse existing Q&A, there are lots of existing questions on this.) But you still need to state a specific question. Please take a skim of [SO Help](https://stackoverflow.com/help) to  learn how to phrase a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all this code will get you the information you need:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time

symbols = ["AAPL", "FB", "TSLA", "DIS"]


def download_data(symbol):
    url = f'https://www.morningstar.com/stocks/xnas/{symbol}/quote'
    s = Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())
    op = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    op.headless = True
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s, options=op)
    driver.get(url)

    # symbol, Last_Close, Market_Cap
    time.sleep(2)


    last_close = driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH,
                                         value='//*[@id="__layout"]/div/div[2]/div[3]/main/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/sal-components/section/div/div/div/sal-components-quote/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/ul/li[1]/div/div[2]')
    market_cap = driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH,
                                          value='//*[@id="__layout"]/div/div[2]/div[3]/main/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/sal-components/section/div/div/div/sal-components-quote/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/ul/li[7]/div/div[2]')
    return symbol, last_close.text, market_cap.text


for symbol in symbols:
    print(download_data(symbol))
```

The output looks like this:

```
('AAPL', '164.51', '2.6529 Tril')
('FB', '316.56', '843.3460 Bil')
('TSLA', '996.27', '947.9256 Bil')
```

The page for Disney actually doesn't exist so you might want to consider checking the url.

You can go through and save it as you want in a data frame to export to csv. I would suggest using Selenium instead of Beautiful Soup. You eliminate the headache of trying to find information that is dynamically rendered using Javascript... sometimes Beautiful Soup has trouble there. Selenium acts just like you would when you visit a webpage.

Also in your code, you try `soup = BS(url)`. I believe you need to make a HTTP requests using the `requests` library in python, but I haven't used `BS` in a while.

Comment: Thank you very much Joe!
I tried to run it on Spyder (Python 3.9) but it shows the an error message. I downloaded chromedriver.exe to my computer (Windows 10) but I am not sure why it does not work... :(
Tried to research on google in the last few hours but still no luck... can you help me please

Error Message:
    from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'webdriver_manager'

Comment: you need to open a terminal and type pip install webdriver-manager. Hit the windows key and type cmd and enter. This opens a black terminal window then type that line.

Comment: the code i included in my answer downloads the chrome driver and everything for you. All you need is the selenium module and webdriver-manager module. If you don't have selenium you can type into the terminal pip install selenium. Pip is a package manager... helps you download modules from PyPI

Comment: @Obe Did this end up solving your issue? If it did I would appreciate you marking it as correct, otherwise I can try to assist further!

Comment: Thanks again Joe! Yes, your code has solved my issue.

Comment: Hi again Joe,
I am trying to extract another data from the same website and would like to use your method. Can you educate me how you arrived to the components address?
**Your components address**
[@id="__layout"]/div/div[2]/div[3]/main/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/sal-components/section/div/div/div/sal-components-quote/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/ul/li[1]/div/div[2]')
**Data I am trying to extract**
'<div class="dp-name">
              Beta<span>
                (5-Year)</span></div>'
[link](https://www.morningstar.com/stocks/xnas/aapl/quote)

Answer (score 1):

Developing a scraper to extract data from a website will be slower to react to live market conditions than using something closer to the original source of data. There are a variety of stock packages that are very useful. Here are some useful links to using Pandas DataReader, yfinance:

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6826/techniques-for-collecting-stock-data-with-python/
https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-get-stock-data-using-python-c0de1df17e75

Personally I prefer to use Pandas as its been more reliable for me and all my data generally ends up in a panda's dataframe anyhow. DataReader can extract directly from Morningstar as well: https://pandas-datareader.readthedocs.io/en/v0.6.0/readers/morningstar.html

Additionally, Quandl is great for analyzing historic data if you are interested in developing an in-depth trading system.
https://analyzingalpha.com/nasdaq-data-link-quandl-python-api

Comment: Thanks Mr. Me! I will read and test out Pandas soon :)